# imagemagick fails with dyld: Library not loaded

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, open-source, image-processing

After wasting a lot of time until finally finding a solution, I decided to share this with the community.

The problem:

```
convert
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/little-cms2/lib/liblcms2.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/convert
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

This kept happening even after updating ImageMagick:

```
brew upgrade imagemagick
```

so what's the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the error, we identify the missing file:

```
/usr/local/opt/little-cms2/lib/liblcms2.2.dylib
```

The first step is to make sure that the library is actually existing:

```
find /usr -name '*liblcms*'
find: /usr/sbin/authserver: Permission denied
/usr/local/lib/liblcms.1.0.19.dylib
/usr/local/lib/liblcms.1.dylib
/usr/local/lib/liblcms.a
/usr/local/lib/liblcms.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms/1.19_1/lib/liblcms.1.0.19.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms/1.19_1/lib/liblcms.1.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms/1.19_1/lib/liblcms.a
/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms/1.19_1/lib/liblcms.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms2/2.9/lib/liblcms2.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms2/2.9/lib/liblcms2.a
/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms2/2.9/lib/liblcms2.2.dylib
```

So we can see that it does exist as `/usr/local/Cellar/little-cms2/2.9/lib/liblcms2.2.dylib`.

We need to create a symbolic link that will make *convert* find the missing file. It is possible that the *brew* installation script was missing to do that.

The way to create a symlink goes like this:

```
ln -s <exisiting file> <pointer to create>
```

So the final solution is simply this:

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/little-cms2/2.9 /usr/local/opt/little-cms2
```

Let's verify:

```
convert
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-0 Q16 x86_64 2020-04-04 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2020 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(3.1) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms ltdl lzma openexr png ps tiff webp xml zlib
Usage: convert [options ...] file [ [options ...] file ...] [options ...] file
...
```

Mission completed :)

Comment: Awesome! I know the system won’t let you select your own answer for a while, but please mark the check when you get a chance. Thanks for the solid Q and A